# My event receiver to create pages automatically only creates one page. How can i debug whats going on with my code?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, application-pages

My code for my feature's event receiver is as shown below. I need it to create all 3 pages **test1,test2,test3.aspx** but it only creates **test1.aspx** in the folder SitePages.

What could be wrong in this code?

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
        string template = "spstd1.aspx";

        string[] pages = { "test1.aspx", "test2.aspx", "test3.aspx" };

        foreach (string s in pages)
        {
            try
            {
                using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://labenv/"))
                {
                    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        string newFilename = s;
                        string templateFilename = template;

                        string hive = SPUtility.GetGenericSetupPath("TEMPLATE\\1033\\STS\\DOCTEMP\\SMARTPGS\\");
                        FileStream stream = new FileStream(hive + templateFilename, FileMode.Open);
                        SPFolder libraryFolder = web.GetFolder("SitePages");
                        SPFileCollection files = libraryFolder.Files;
                        SPFile newFile = files.Add(newFilename, stream);


                        if (newFile.CheckOutType != SPFile.SPCheckOutType.None)
                        {
                            newFile.CheckIn("CheckedIn");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                //Means page already exists, in this case ignore
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: You can debug attaching w3wp.exe process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To debug your application you have to attach VS to the process **w3wp.exe**

You can also use the event log, to log some messages.

Instead of catching the exception when the file exists, try to use:

```
  string fileUrl = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", web.Url, "SitePages", newFileName);
  SPFile file = web.GetFile(fileUrl);
  if (!file.Exists) //add
```

[Debug WSP SharePoint](http://www.sharepoint-insight.com/2009/01/09/how-to-debug-custom-application-pages-in-sharepoint/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! The debugger sais that the hive process was being used, so it couldnt be accessed for the second time. I changed the code to the edit above and it works!

Answer (score 2):

The debug tips from Nk SP and Hardik me helped me find the problem. The hive process was already in use so at the second attempt the debugger showed that the process was already in use. I changed the code to this and it worked

```
using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                string hive = SPUtility.GetGenericSetupPath("TEMPLATE\\1033\\STS\\DOCTEMP\\SMARTPGS\\");
                string templateFilename = template;
                FileStream stream = new FileStream(hive + templateFilename, FileMode.Open);

                    foreach (string s in pages)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            string newFilename = s;

                            SPFolder libraryFolder = web.GetFolder("SitePages");
                            SPFileCollection files = libraryFolder.Files;
                            SPFile newFile = files.Add(newFilename, stream);

                            if (newFile.CheckOutType != SPFile.SPCheckOutType.None)
                            {
                                newFile.CheckIn("CheckedIn");
                            }
                        }
                       catch
                       {
                            //Means page already exists, in this case ignore
                       }
                    }
            }
```